# Having problems to plot this equation, giving wrong plot

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, equation

I'm trying to plot a radioisotope's power output by time. For this, I've found the following equation:

[image: the equation]

without the exponential at the end it works but I need the difference by time so I need to use it but I can't make that part work.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

ln2=0.693
avon=6.02214076*(10**23)
mevj=1.6*(10**(-13))
t = np.array(range(50))

co60 = (((ln2)/(5.27*365*24*3600))*((avon)*mevj*2.505/60))/(2.718**((ln2)/(5.27*365*24*3600)*(t)))) 

plt.plot(t, co60, label='co60')
```

This gives a wrong output. I can't get an exponential plot. I used 2.718 for e since when I use math.exp it gives errors. The correct output must be like the black line.

[image]

I think I'm having troubles with using the mathematical dynamics of python and couldn't interpret the equation correctly. Could you help?

Thanks.

Comment: A quick remark: when working with numpy arrays you need `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`. Also, you seem to have a superfluous `)` in your code.  The value you multiply by `t` is extremely small, about `4.17e-09`.   Maybe you want `t` much larger to compensate?  Leaving out `*365*24*3600` seems to give a curve a bit similar to the example.

Comment: ` it gives errors` - what errors?  Don't be vague about this.

Comment: uranium, if your time unit is a year, then you have arbitrarily assigned an half-life of ~160 MILLION years to your ⁶⁰Co, and your power output is essentially constant over JUST 50 years...